# How can I tell when a UWP TreeView has been changed by user's drag and drop

Tags: c#, uwp, treeview

I have a UWP TreeView which users can edit. I need to persist any changes they make. I manage additions and deletions, so that's not a problem. But users can drag and drop TreeViewNodes to change the structure of the tree.

Are there event(s)  that would let me know about changes made that way.

I've tried the various Drag and Drop events without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are there event(s) that would let me know about changes made that way.

The dragging operation of `TreeViewNode` could be detected by `DragItems` relative events, for example, [`DragItemsStarting`](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemsstarting) and [`DragItemsCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.dragitemscompleted). And these events need to be subscribed for the [`TreeViewList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.treeviewlist) which you could find inside the default style of `TreeView`. For example:

```
<TreeView >
    <TreeView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TreeView"> 
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeView">
                        <TreeViewList x:Name="ListControl" AllowDrop="True" DragItemsStarting="ListControl_DragItemsStarting" CanReorderItems="True" CanDragItems="True" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TreeViewItemStyle}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TreeViewItemDataTemplate}">
                            <TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                                <TransitionCollection>
                                    <ContentThemeTransition/>
                                    <ReorderThemeTransition/>
                                    <EntranceThemeTransition IsStaggeringEnabled="False"/>
                                </TransitionCollection>
                            </TreeViewList.ItemContainerTransitions>
                        </TreeViewList>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Style> 
    <TreeView.RootNodes>
        <TreeViewNode Content="Flavors" IsExpanded="True" >
            <TreeViewNode.Children>
                <TreeViewNode Content="Vanilla"/>
                <TreeViewNode Content="Strawberry"/>
                <TreeViewNode Content="Chocolate"/>
            </TreeViewNode.Children>
        </TreeViewNode>
    </TreeView.RootNodes>
</TreeView>

 private void ListControl_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
 {

 }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! I was subscribing to the events from the TreeView itself, not the embedded TreeViewList.  Thanks very much!